# Como alinhar Um texto melhor HTML

Tags: html, css

Bom quero Alinhar um texto ou uma imagem  em qualquer lugar da tela por Exemplo:

```
     Um texto aqui outro                           



 outro aqui                                                              e aqui
```

Comment: Depende da estrutura do seu HTML. Você pode usar `text-align`, `margin` etc no CSS, por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Para posicionar elementos de forma arbitrária em qualquer lugar da tela você pode usar o estilo `position` com `fixed` (posição em relação ao *body*). Este último, o elemento ficará fixo na tela, ou seja, caso haja *scroll*, ele não se moverá.

Além do `position`, você usa mais dois estilos, o `top` (distância à partir do topo) e o `left` (distância à partir da esquerda).

> Existe também o `position: absolute` que não torna o elemento fixo,
>   mas ele se posicionará dentro do *elemento-pai* caso este possua
>   definido algum `position` (`absolute`, `relative` ou `fixed`). Caso não, ele tomará por base o `body` ou, caso haja, o primeiro elemento acima na árvore que possuir um dos estilos acima.

Exemplo com `fixed`:

```css
span{
   position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<span style="top: 0; left: 50px;">Um texto aqui outro</span>
<span style="top: 100px; left: 20px;">outro aqui</span>
<span style="top: 100px; left: 500px;">e aqui</span>
```

Exemplo com `absolute`:

```css
span{
   position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<span style="top: 0; left: 50px;">Um texto aqui outro</span>
<span style="top: 100px; left: 20px;">outro aqui</span>
<span style="top: 100px; left: 500px;">e aqui</span>
```

Como dito, o `absolute` não torna o elemento fixo e se posiciona dentro do *elemento-pai*. No exemplo acima, como os elementos não estão dentro de um elemento específico, eles são posicionados tendo como base o `body`.